# Recycler view focusing another text view in other rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my project i have a recycler view which contains a text view in every row. when i select a text view in a row text views in some random rows are also selected and also whatever is typed into it, it is also showing in those rows.Here is my code. 
onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MainContentViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.e("Sony","onBindViewHolder");
    Item currentItem = items.get(position);
    if (currentItem.imageURL != null) {
        imageLoader.get(currentItem.imageURL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                Log.e("Sony","onResponseImage");
                holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Sony","onErrorImage");
                holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_product);
            }
        });
    }
    //holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL().getContent());

    holder.itemPrice.setText(currentItem.price + "");
    holder.itemName.setText(currentItem.itemName);
}
```

ViewHolder

```
 public MainContentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgItemPic);
        itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblItemName);
        itemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lblItemPrice);
        txtQty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        btnAddToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAddToCart);
        btnAddToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Item item = items.get(getPosition());
                CartMessageHandler.showToastMessage(context, item.itemName + " : " + item.price, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });
    }
```

activity onCreate

```
 mainListView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
    mainListView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
    recyclerViewListAdapter = new MainContentRecyclerAdapter(this);
    mainListView.setAdapter(recyclerViewListAdapter);
    getData("fruits%20&%20vegetables");
    mainListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Custom Row for recyclerView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardItemHolderRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgItemPic"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/itemImageDimen"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/itemImageDimen"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/productImage"
    android:src="@drawable/default_product"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginWidgetTopMargin" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgItemPic"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardItemHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginWidgetTopMargin"
        android:text="Item  Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblItemPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginWidgetTopMargin"
        android:text="Rs.250"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryColor" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginWidgetTopMargin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblItemQty"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/quantity"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtQty"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddToCart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cart_a16"
        android:text="@string/addToCart" />
</LinearLayout>
```

what is wrong in my code? Can anyone suggest a way to fix this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecyclerView reuses row views that was created earlier. That's why you see earlier typed text in random rows of your RecyclerView: you simply don't reset row view stuff state in *onBindViewHolder*.

So to avoid bug you should reset components state in *onBindViewHolder*: clear *txtQty* and etc. In case of expensive or heavyweight data documentation is recommended releasing this data with [setRecyclerListener(..)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setRecyclerListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.RecyclerListener)).